# How to remove common values from two string lists

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I'm new to C++ and after googling quite a bit I haven't found a solution.
I'm making a Hexgame, and I'm trying to check if there is a winner.
My function checkpath, gets a list of places it has visited (usedPlaces), and creates the list Possible, of places it can check next from the current position.
So I want to delete the places I have already visited from Possible.
The error I'm getting atm is "List iterators incompatible"
I've tried things, but they mostly end up giving me other errors

```
for (list<string>::iterator it = possible.begin(); it != possible.end(); it++)
{
    for (list<string>::iterator it2 = usedPlaces.begin(); it2 != usedPlaces.end();)
    {
        if (it == it2)
        {
            possible.remove(*it);
        }
        else
        {
            it2++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
if (it == it2)
```

you're comparing an iterator into one list to an iterator into another list. Those would never compare equal anyway, and it's handy that your implementation debugs this for you. Even if you fixed the comparison (to `*it == *it2`), the code would still be buggy due to how and when `it` gets incremented and inefficient (due to the extra searching of `possible`). A functional version would be:

```
for (list<string>::iterator it = possible.begin(); it != possible.end(); /* nothing */)
{
    list<string>::iterator it2 = std::find(usedPlaces.begin(), usedPlaces.end(), *it);
    if (it2 != usedPlaces.end()) {
        it = possible.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

But this is complicated to write and error-prone. I'd prefer to use [`list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove), which takes a predicate and removes all the elements for which that predicate returns true:

```
possible.remove_if([&](const std::string& place){
    return std::find(usedPlaces.begin(), usedPlaces.end(), place)
        != usedPlaces.end();
});
```

That's much more direct.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to removes **string** objects that are the same, so the comparison should look at the string objects. Instead of

```
if (it == it2)
```

it should be

```
if (*it == *it2)
```

Comment: I tried it, but it gives me the error "List iterator not dereferencable"

Comment: That's because after `possible.erase(*it)` the iterator `it` is invalid, you need to to `it = possible.erase(it)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The operation `it == it2` checks if one iterator points to the same element as the other iterator. That is never true, because those two iterators are coming from two different lists.

What you probably want to compare are the *contents* of each list element, i.e. `*it`.

Note, there may be other problems in your code. E.g. after you call `possible.remove(*it)` your iterator `it` is no longer referencing any elements of the list, therefore you won't be able to increment it in the next iteration of the loop.

Consider using [`possible.erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/) and getting its result. You will need, most likely, change your outher loop though.